# $n$th derivative of $\frac{1}{\sin{x}}$ and $\frac{x}{\sin{x}}$.

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find a general pattern for $\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d} x^n}\frac{1}{\sin{x}}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d} x^n}\frac{x}{\sin{x}}$ but I can't seem to arrive at it. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to evaluate those derivatives at some given point (e.g, at $x=0$), you don't necessarily need a general formula.

Comment: @Babak: can you elaborate ? (By the way $x=0$ isn't an option.)

Comment: I can't explain it here, so I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \dfrac{1}{\sin(x)} = \dfrac{P_n(\cos(x))}{\sin^{n+1}(x)}$$
where $P_n$ are polynomials satisfying the recurrence

$$ \eqalign{P_{n+1}(t) &= (t^2-1) P_n'(t) - (n+1) t P_n(t)\cr
P_0(t) &= 1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Case $\displaystyle \frac{x}{\sin(x)}$.

It's $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(xf(x))=n\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}f(x)+x\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)$$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Proof by induction.

Set $\displaystyle f(x):=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ and use the solution of *Robert Israel* above.

Answer (score 0):

(Actually, this is not an answer. I'm just elaborating my last comment.)

As I already said, if you want to evaluate derivatives of a function at a given point, you're not necessarily required to find its general $n$th derivative expression.

As an example, if you were asked to *"Find the 51st derivative of $f(x)=1/\sin{x}$ at $x=\pi/2$"* then you could find it easily without having to extract the general derivative formula. To find the answer you could define a new function $g(x)=f(x+\pi/2)=1/\cos{x}$. Since it's an even function (i.e., $g(-x)=g(x)$) its odd derivatives (e.g., 1st, 3rd, and also 51st) are zero at $x=0$. But since $g(x)$ is a simple shift of $f(x)$, then $g^{(n)}(x)=f^{(n)}(x+\pi/2)$, which by letting $x=0$ would be $g^{(51)}(0)=f^{(51)}(\pi/2)=0$. As you see, you didn't have to find a general formula for $f(x)$'s $n$th derivative.